# Writing custom gradle plugin with non-transitive dependency

Tags: plugins, gradle

I am trying to implement a gradle plugin which in turn depends on an another gradle plugin.  Here is a snippet of my plugin's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
  }
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    compile 'com.example:otherplugin:[0.1,)'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: mavenLocal())
            pom.groupId = 'com.example'
            pom.version = '0.5'
            pom.artifactId = 'myplugin'
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using range dependency and not particular about any version of the **'otherplugin'**. When the user includes my plugin in his build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.example:otherplugin:1.0', 'com.example:myplugin:2.3'
    }
}
```

Gradle always uses the latest version of **'com.example:otherplugin'** to process his project. Ideally, I would like the version specified by the user to be downloaded, and used by gradle.

I believe this is a problem with my plugin's build.gradle. How can I modify my plugin's build.gradle so that, this transitive dependency is avoided ?

Comment: Users will be able to force the transitive plugin version in the normal way (e.g `buildscript { configurations.classpath.resolutionStrategy.force("com.example:otherplugin:0.3") }`).

Comment: That's the answer! Thanks.